# Langchain PyPDFLoader read from Azure Blob Storage mount point in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, langchain

I am working on Azure Databricks and trying to read a PDF file located in Azure Blob Storage. Also, I am using Langchain PyPDFLoader to read the PDF. According to the examples I have checked, PyPDFLoader gets in the path of the PDF file, so I provide the path in the mount point, but it does not work.

Here, I show the code snapshot:

```
blob_path = f"wasbs://{container_name}@{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net"
account_url = f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net"
account_key = "******************"


dbutils.fs.mount(source = blob_path,
             mount_point = f"/mnt/{mount_point}/",
             extra_configs = {account_url: account_key})

loader = PyPDFLoader(f'/mnt/{mount_point}/raw-docs/doc.pdf')
pages = loader.load()
```

I get the following error:

"**ValueError**: File path /mnt/mpoint/raw-docs/doc.pdf is not a valid file or url"

I have tried changing the PDF location and also with some other functions to read the file, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the pdf path with `dbfs` since your not using any spark context.
The **PyPDFLoader** searches the path through driver filesystem so you need to give path from root.
`/dbfs/mount_path`.

Alter the path like below.

```
  loader = PyPDFLoader(f'/dbfs/mnt/{mount_point}/testfolder/sample.pdf')
  pages = loader.load()
  pages[0]
```

Output:
[image]

Refer [this](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html) documentation to know more about working with files in databricks.

Comment: Thanks. I had the path starting with dbfs:/ .. Replacing it with /dbfs/ fixed the issue.